How to open Windows 10 drive from Ubuntu 24.04?
I have a computer with two storage drives, an m.2 and an SSD. The m.2 contains my Windows EFI and data partitions (the only OS I used until now).
Recently I installed Ubuntu to my SSD but forgot to take the files I wanted off of the m.2 drive. I am not dual-booting, nor did I format either of the m.2 partitions. When I try to boot Windows again, it is giving me a blue screen. I mounted the m.2 data partition to my Linux system, but I can only see three files, one of which is a dumpstack.log file.
Can I open the m.2 data partition (NTFS, GPT) from my Linux machine?
=======================================================================
Edit: I have a Kingston sa2000m81000g M.2 and a Samsung 870 Evo ssd. When I run testdisk I get the warnings:
"Warning: number of heads/cylinders mismatches 255 (NTFS) != 64 (HD)"
"Warning: number of sectors per track mismatches 63 (NTFS) != 32 (HD)"

Ubuntu without any additional configuration read NTFS drives. If both drives are connected it should out of the box without any additional configuration be able to access the drive

To fix the Windows boot BSOD, you'll need to use a Linux utility to fix the BCD Store on Windows, of which is causing the boot BSOD (when Linux is installed alongside Windows, using bootrec to fix the BCD Store overwrites GRUB, being the only time a Linux utility is required to fix a Windows issue). For accessing the m.2 from Ubuntu, did you fully shutdown Windows prior to booting Ubuntu (Fast Startup or similar must be disabled in the UEFI firmware)? If not, resolve the boot issue, boot into Windows, fully shut it down, boot back into Ubuntu and see if it's resolved

By default, Linux should be able to mount and to read any NTFS partition. If that partition is marked "dirty", i.e., in use, such as when the Windows OS is using Fast Boot or Hibernation, it is only safe to read, not to write to it, though. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23843/mount-ntfs-partition-on-startup-in-ubuntu, for mounting it automatically.

The messages you're getting indicate the disk may have a problem, not that Ubuntu is unable to read a Windows formatted partition.
